# Is there an idiom for "people are the same everywhere"?

Tags: idiom-requests

I am looking for an idiom that expresses the notion that no matter where you go, people are fundamentally the same.

Comment: It's funny, I can recall an idiom for this in Spanish but not in English.

Comment: I don't think there's an idiom for it. We just say "People are all alike" or "People are alike all over".

Comment: In Scotland we might say ["We're a' Jock Tamson's bairns"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jock_Tamson%27s_Bairns), but not sure that phrase travels well.

Comment: @psosuna ¡Qué no te preocupes tío, pues pasa eso aun en las mejores familias, no lo sabías? :)

Comment: @tchrist De eso hay aquí y en China. ;)

Comment: People are people.

Comment: [We all put our pants on one leg at a time](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/put+your+pants+on+one+leg+at+a+time)

Comment: I've heard the phrase you used, "people are the same everywhere", quite a few times.

Comment: Would a short tale count? I’m thinking of the famous one about a newcomer who asks a local about what kind of people live here, and the local answers...

Answer (score 1):

"We're all cut from the same cloth."

cf:

“Everyone is kneaded out the the same clay, but not baked in the same kiln.”

-- Yiddish proverb

Comment: Does it mean that people are the same everywhere?

Comment: Everyone eats with a single hand. We are all animals with a better brain.

Answer (score 0):

We’re all born the same, then we separate.

Answer (score 0):

It's even the name of a book too:

[Everyone poops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everyone_Poops).